# How to convert this "Jan 1 2018 12:00AM" type of date formate into only month like "January" usiing Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need some help, when i import my data into SQL Server from excel sheet the date will show this format "Jan  1 2018 12:00AM" but i want only month like this "January", I'm using asp.net.

Thank you,
Kandarp Rami

Comment: will help with spelling

Comment: You are looking for [DateTime.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_DateTime_TryParse_System_String_System_DateTime__)

Comment: You first convert the string to a `DateTime` variable. You then use the DateTime format functions to format only the date. Where exactly in this are you getting stuck?

Comment: thanks everyone, but i'm already figure out myself,